# How to calculate mean of specific rows in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe with 11 000k rows. There are multiple columns but I am interested only in 2 of them: Name and Value. One name can repeat itself multiple times among rows. I want to calculate the average value for each name and create a new dataframe with the average value for each name. I don't really know how to walk through rows and how to calculate the average. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
Name     DataType    TimeStamp           Value Quality
Food   Float       2019-01-01 13:00:00  105.75      122
Food    Float      2019-01-01 17:30:00  11.8110352  122
Food   Float       2019-01-01 17:45:00  12.7932892      122
Water       Float      2019-01-01 14:01:00  16446.875   122
Water       Float      2019-01-01 14:00:00  146.875     122

RangeIndex: 11140487 entries, 0 to 11140486
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Name              object
Value        object
```

This is what I have and I know it is really noob ish but I am having a difficult time walking through rows.

```
for i in range(0, len(df):
if((df.iloc[i]['DataType']!='Undefined')):
    print df.loc[df['Name'] == df.iloc[i]['Name'], df.iloc[i]['Value']].mean()
```

Comment: I could answer I only you have posted a copyable data sample instead of an image, so that I could test my code. Hint: use `groupby` and `mean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid as much as possible to iterate rows in a dataframe, because it is very unefficient...

`groupby` is the way to go when you want to apply the same processing to various *groups* of rows identified by their values in one or more columns. Here what you want is (*):

```
df.groupby('TagName')['Sample_value'].mean().reset_index()
```

it gives as expected:

```
     TagName  Sample_value
0      Steam  1.081447e+06
1  Utilities  3.536931e+05
```

---

Details on the magic words:

- `groupby`: identifies the column(s) used to group the rows (same values)
- `['Sample_values']`: restrict the groupby object to the column of interest
- `mean()`: computes the mean per group
- `reset_index()`: by default the grouping columns go into the index, which is fine for the mean operation. `reset_index` make them back normal columns

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. There is a little problem, seems like Samples_Value is object type. I tried to convert it to numeric like this: df['Samples_Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Samples_Value'], downcast='Float') BUT I still get an error (alueError: Unable to parse string "Sheet break Start" at position 972918)

Comment: df['Samples_Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Samples_Value'],errors='ignore'), still doesn't work. Tells me there are no numerical values to aggregate.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to walk through the rows, you can just take all of the fields that match your criteria

```py
d = {'col1': [1,2,1,2,1,2], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#iterate over all unique entries in col1
for entry in  df["col1"].unique():
    # get all the col2 values where col1 is the current iter of col1 entries
    meanofcurrententry=df[df["col1"]==entry]["col2"].mean()
    print(meanofcurrententry)
```

This is not a full solution, but I think it helps more to understand the necessary logic. You still need to wrap it up into your own dataframe, however it hopefuly helps to understand how to use the indexing

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) functionality is what you want. You define the column where your groups are and then you can take the [`mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) of each group. An example from the documentation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'B': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'C': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2]}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df.groupby('A').mean()
```

Output:

```
     B         C
A
1  3.0  1.333333
2  4.0  1.500000
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
df.groupby('TagName')['Samples_value'].mean()
```

**Edit:** So, I applied the code to your provided input dataframe and following is the output:

```
TagName
Steam        1.081447e+06
Utilities    3.536931e+05
Name: Sample_value, dtype: float64
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, thank you for your fast reply. but the problem is Samples_value is object type, not numerical. I tried to covert it to numerical and I am getting an weird error ("(alueError: Unable to parse string "Sheet break Start" at position 972918)

Comment: Is the error occurring, when you perform this code: `df['Sample_value'] = df['Sample_value'].astype('float64')` or is it occuring when you perform the `groupby()`? Also does the column `Samples_value` contain anything other than floats?

Comment: after performing your line you've just given me i get this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float.

Comment: Could be that there are some strange values in your columns. With `df[~df['Sample_value'].map(np.isreal)]` you can filter out the rows where the value is no float. Then you can for example delete these specific rows.